# How to write an implicit class for a generalised type

Tags: scala

I have written an implicit class to add some operations to a List:

```
implicit class ListEnricher[T](list: List[T]) {
    
    def replace(i: Int)(f: T => T): List[T] = list.patch(i, List(f(list(i))), 1)

    def replace(i: Int, t: T, extend: Boolean = false): List[T] =
        if (extend && i >= list.size) insert(i, t)
        else replace(i)(_ => t)

    def insert(i: Int, t: T): List[T] = list.patch(i, List(t), 0)

    def removeAt(i: Int): List[T] = list.patch(i, List(), 1)
}
```

I want to make this class more general so as to be able to use it for other SeqLike classes such as a Seq. So I defined it as follows:

```
implicit class SeqLikeEnricher[T, S <: SeqLike[T, S]](seq: S) {

    def replace(i: Int)(f: T => T)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]): S =
        seq.patch[T, S](i, Seq(f(seq(i))), 1)

    def replace(i: Int, t: T, extend: Boolean = false)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]): S =
        if (extend && i >= seq.size) insert(i, t)
        else replace(i)(_ => t)

    def insert(i: Int, t: T)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]): S = seq.patch[T, S](i, Seq(t), 0)

    def removeAt(i: Int)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S, T, S]): S = seq.patch[T, S](i, Seq(), 1)
}
```

But if I try to use the class thus:

```
val seq = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
SeqLikeEnricher(seq).replace(1, 2)
```

I get the following compiler error:

> Inferred type arguments [Nothing,Seq[Int]] do not conform to method
> SeqLikeEnricher's type parameter bounds [T,S <:
> scala.collection.SeqLike[T,S]]    SeqLikeEnricher(seq).replace(1, 2)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definition of the class to this:

```scala
implicit class SeqLikeEnricher[T, S](seq: SeqLike[T, S])
```

This will fix your issue.

If you use the first implementation, the compiler won't be able to infer `T`, so it will assume `T` is `Nothing`.